# Написать функцию, которая возвращает расстояние (расстояние Минковского)

Tags: python, math

Kак написать функцию к заданию: "Написать функцию, которая возвращает расстояние (расстояние Минковского) порядка p между двумя точками, координаты которых являются входными аргументами. Значение порядка p по умолчанию 2."?

```
def nth_root(value, n_root):
    root_value = 1/float(n_root)
    return round ((value) ** (root_value),3)

def minkowski_distance(x,y,p=2):
    return nth_root(sum(pow(abs(a-b),p)
    for a,b in zip(x, y)),p)

print minkowski_distance([1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 0])
print minkowski_distanceprint minkowski_distance([2, 2, 3, 5], [6, 1, 8, 2], 4)
```

Comment: а что именно у вас не получается? где возникли затруднения?

Comment: SO не является сайтом где пишут код по вашему заказу. Покажите что вы сделали и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Вы даже не попытались что либо сделать самостоятельно. Вы просите выполнить задание за Вас. При такой постановке вопроса оценку за задание тоже получать будет кто-то другой

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE

Comment: @MaxU я просто не пойму в какую сторону копать, пытался решать по разному но не получается, понимаю что SO не пишет за тебя код, но вот очень хочу понять как высчитывается это расстояние.

Comment: @AndreySindeev, вставьте ваш вариант в вопрос, нажав на [кнопку править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/721515/edit). Это не важно если код нерабочий / некрасивый / неоптимальный - именно для этого и создан SO - чтобы помогать тем, кто не боится пробовать что-то сделать самому... ;)

Comment: @MaxU я вроде как докапался до истины с помощью гугла  и немного подумав нужно просто было ещё одну функцию дописать которая берёт корень от суммы абсолютных разностей, возведённых в р-тую степень.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin я понял извините, я просто не хотел выкладывать код изначально, теперь буду это делать всегда,какой бы он не был.

Answer (score 5):

```
def minkowski(a, b, p=2):
    assert len(a) == len(b), "'a' and 'b' must be of the same length"
    return pow(sum((abs(x-y)**p) for x,y in zip(a,b)), 1/p)
```

Тест:

```
In [102]: print(minkowski([1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 0]))
3.0

In [105]: print(minkowski([1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 0], 4))
2.39678172692843
```

Comment: огромное вам спасибо, очень интересно!

Comment: @AndreySindeev, всегда рад помочь :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def nth_root(value, n_root):
    root_value = 1/float(n_root)
    return round ((value) ** (root_value),3)

def minkowski_distance(x,y,p=2):
    return nth_root(sum(pow(abs(a-b),p)
    for a,b in zip(x, y)),p)

print minkowski_distance([1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 0])
print minkowski_distanceprint minkowski_distance([2, 2, 3, 5], [6, 1, 8, 2], 4)
```